# Fill PayPal order script using onOpen() function

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I'm trying to implement the PayPal SDK on my site, and thought this should work:

```
<body onload="writeOrderCode()">
```

The JS file with this function was loaded in the `<head>` section. The function writes the code to a var, which is then inserted as `$("paypalscript").innerHTML`. The `<script id="paypalscript">` tag is at the place in the HTML where the button should be drawn. Here's an example of what I had in mind:

```html
<head>
  <-- Load PayPal SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[CLIENT_ID]"></script>
    <-- Load JS file with the function -->
      <script src="/myJSfile.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="writeOrderCode(5)">
  <div id="paypal-button-container">
    <script id="paybtn">
      <-- JS function should write order code here -->
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
function writeOrderCode(x) {
  var ps = '    paypal.Buttons({\n';
    ps += ' style: {\n';
    ps += '     layout:  "vertical",\n';
    // Calc choices about values or which properties to include //
    ps += '     color:   ' + (x > 2 ? "gold" : "black") + ',\n';
    ps += '     shape:   "pill",\n';
    ps += '     label:   "pay"\n';
    ps += '   },\n';
    ps += '}).render("#paypal-button-container")\n';
  // insert into script tag in HTML //
  document.getElementById("paybtn").innerHTML = ps;
}
```

The problem is the entire page gets drawn before the new code is inserted, so it has no effect, except that it triggers an error:

> Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could
> not be found.

It references a mile-long URL at "https://tracking.qa.paypal.com".
Obviously this is coming from the PayPal file that was also loaded in the `<head>` section, but I don't understand why this error happens when I write the code from JS, but not if the same code is in the script tag to start with. Is PayPal trying to write code to the same tag?

I suspect this might be done with a callback, to make sure the code was written before the rest of the page was rendered, but I'm afraid I'm sadly incompetent and confused by callbacks. Any help on how this might be done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us your function, or what it wrote to your page DOM, so it's hard to offer any specific guidance.

But here is a working example:

```
function loadAsync(url, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD', function() {
  paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '0.01'
                }
            }]
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // Show a success message to the buyer
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        });
    }

  }).render('body');
});
```

If you want a full package dedicated to this loading, you can use [paypal-js](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js#using-a-cdn).

Comment: Thank you for the example! It doesn't do exactly what I had in mind, but may be a better approach. I need to learn more about how to use dot syntax, and creating HTML objects from JS.

Comment: You may have no need of a function like loadAsync, if you are able to include a <script> tag to the SDK from the get-go. Looking at your `function writeOrderCode(x)`, it makes no sense -- you should never have to write JS into an element like that.

Comment: Inside paypal.Butons({ style ...   you could call a functin like `getButtonColor()`. , or reference a variable like `buttonColor` if it is in scope, filling the role of your `x`

Comment: You are correct. What I finally figured out is that I can employ JS logic within the button definition. I had wrongly assumed that adding anything extra inside the `paypal.Buttons({  })` would somehow screw things up. Using the button descriptor and x was merely for example. Thanks for your comments!